# Reputation point varies

Tags: support

When i go to my user profile and check server fault site the reputation point showing diffrent(31 reputation points) and when i click on the stack exchange drop down menu on left hand side corner it shows different(lesser reputation points 29).Can anybody tell why so?

Comment: Question is edited and it  has an answer now. Hope question is clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caching... It will fix itself.